# Passar parâmetro de uma função de acordo com o valor clicado com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Preciso passar o valor de uma função de acordo com o valor clicado da mesma. São 3 divs, cada uma é uma galeria. Preciso que ao clicar na opção "veja mais", abra uma página com todas as fotos apenas daquela galeria, porém, não sei como passar o valor da galeria clicada, apenas atribuir o mesmo direto no código. Poderiam ajudar? Carrego a função através do `body onload` na página direcionada, não sei se é a melhor maneira...

A galeria:

```js
while(x <= 3){

            imgs.innerHTML += "<div id='gal"+x+"' class='row'>";
            imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='eight columns'>";
            imgs.innerHTML += "<h4>Galeria "+x+"</h4>"

        for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
            galeria[i] = "foto"+x+"_"+(i+1)+".jpg";
        }


        for(var i = 0; i < galeria.length; i++){
            imgs.innerHTML += "<img src='img/"+galeria[i]+"' class='imgs-galeria'>";
        }

        imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
        imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
        imgs.innerHTML += "<a href='teste.html'><div id='link'><p>Veja mais</p></div>";
        x++;
    }
```

A página `teste.html`:

```html
<body onload="maisGaleria(2);">
<div class="center">
<div class="row">
<div class="four columns top">
    <h5>Nome</h5>
</div>
<div class="eight columns menu">
    <ul>
        <a href="index.html"><li><h4 class="menu-list">Home</h4></li></a>
        <a href="galeria.html"><li><h4 class="menu-list">Galeria</h4></li></a>
        <a href="sobre.html"><li><h4 class="menu-list">Sobre</h4></li></a>
        <a href="contato.html"><li><h4 class="menu-list">Contato</h4></li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row galeria">
<div id="gallery" class="container">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div id="footer">
<div class="four columns">
    <h4>Nome</h4>
</div>
<div class="eight columns img-footer" id="social">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

e a função `maisGaleria(n)`:

```js
function maisGaleria(n){

    var galeria = new Array();
    var img = $("#gallery");

        img.innerHTML = "<div class='row'>";
        img.innerHTML = "<div class='six columns'>";
        //imgs.innerHTML += "<h4>Galeria"+n+"</h4>";

        for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
            galeria[i] = "foto"+n+"_"+(i+1)+".jpg";
        }

        //se utilizar <=galeria.length, ele adicionara um valor vazio, que foi atribuido devido ao (i+1) do outro for.
        for(var i = 0; i < galeria.length; i++){
            img.innerHTML += "<img src='img/"+galeria[i]+"' class='imgs-galeria'>";
        }

        img.innerHTML += "</div>";
        img.innerHTML += "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O meu problema era: Precisava direcionar galerias diferentes para uma mesma página (chamada agora de pics.html) porém, com valores diferentes, para que a mesma página trouxesse imagens da galeria 1, 2 ou 3, sem a necessidade de uma página diferente para cada galeria (pois se houvesse uma página para cada, o usuário ficaria impossibilitado de criar uma nova galeria). O que foi preciso fazer foi passar o número da galeria como parametro para a url a ser direcionada.

Deste modo:

```
window.onload = function(){

    var galeria = new Array();

    var imgs = $("#gallery");
    var x = 1;

while(x <= 3){

            imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='row'>";
            imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='eight columns'>";
            imgs.innerHTML += "<h4>Galeria "+x+"</h4>"

        for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
            galeria[i] = "foto"+x+"_"+(i+1)+".jpg";
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < galeria.length; i++){
            imgs.innerHTML += "<img src='img/"+galeria[i]+"' class='imgs-galeria'>";
        }

        imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
        imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
        imgs.innerHTML += "<a id='veja' href='pics.html?gal="+x+"'><div id='link'><p>Veja mais</p></div>"
     // O ? ao fim da url começa a dar parametros para o link, deste modo o parametro de cada galeria sera respectivo ao seu mesmo valor.
    x++;
}
```

E na página pics.html, bastou chamar a função maisGaleria(n) dando o valor do parametro da url a função:

```
    window.onload = function(){

        /* location.search fara uma busca naquela url, e o metodo split() transforma os elementos em arrays. Nos parenteses ("?gal=") estou mandando separar em arrays sem esse valor, estou separando ele do total, e pegando o segundo [1] valor do array, ja que o primeiro é nulo. Ao final, a variavel x recebe o valor.*/

        var x = location.search.split("?gal=")[1];

        //o y recebe o body
        y = $("#pics");

        //console.log(x);

        //e passa a função mais galeria com o valor do parametro ao body, quando carregar.
        //não preciso passar o html pois ja esta todo na função.

        y.onload = maisGaleria(x);

}

    </script>
</head>
<body id="pics">
<!-- código html -->
```

E a função maisGaleria(n) permaneceu a mesma.

```
function maisGaleria(n){

    var galeria = new Array();
    var img = $("#gallery");

        img.innerHTML = "<div class='row'>";
        img.innerHTML += "<div class='six columns'>";
        //img.innerHTML += "<h4>Galeria"+n+"</h4>";

        for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
            galeria[i] = "foto"+n+"_"+(i+1)+".jpg";
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < galeria.length; i++){
            img.innerHTML += "<img src='img/"+galeria[i]+"' class='imgs-galeria'>";
        }

        img.innerHTML += "</div>";
        img.innerHTML += "</div>";
}
```

Essa é a minha primeira resposta no SOpt, desculpem se não fui claro, espero que sirva de ajuda para outros usuários que tiverem duvidas.

Answer (score 3):

O melhor seria gerar o HTML no lado do servidor. É possível abrir uma nova janela com JavaScript e adicionar-lhe HTML, mas o melhor é mesmo no servidor.

Fazendo isso no JavaScript sugiro uma nova função, e sugiro criares uma maneira de a tua função retornar HTML, sem escrever diretamente. Assim, podias usar o HTML que ela gera noutra função como esta:

```js
function abreJanela(nrGaleria) {
    var novaJanela = window.open();
    var html = maisGaleria(n, true);
    $(novaJanela.document.body).html(html);
}
```

Vejo alguns problemas na tua função. Estás a usar `.innerHTML` em objetos jQuery e a iterar uma array como um objeto. Sugiro alterares a função para o exemplo em baixo. Repara que juntei um novo parâmetro para ela retornar o HTML:

```js
function maisGaleria(n, novoElemento){

    var galeria = [];
    var img = novoElemento ? document.createElement('div') : document.getElementById("#gallery");

        img.innerHTML = "<div class='row'>";
        img.innerHTML = "<div class='six columns'>";
        //imgs.innerHTML += "<h4>Galeria"+n+"</h4>";

        for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
            galeria.push("foto"+n+"_"+(i+1)+".jpg");
        }

        //se utilizar <=galeria.length, ele adicionara um valor vazio, que foi atribuido devido ao (i+1) do outro for.
        for(var i = 0; i < galeria.length; i++){
            img.innerHTML += "<img src='img/"+galeria[i]+"' class='imgs-galeria'>";
        }
        imgs.innerHTML += "<a href='teste.html' onclick='maisGaleria(" + x + "); return false;'><div id='link'><p>Veja mais</p></div>";
        img.innerHTML += "</div>";
        img.innerHTML += "</div>";
        return img;
}
```

Repara que juntei também na função o que o @bfavaretto já tinha sugerido.

Comment: obrigado ! Porém a página continua abrindo sem nenhuma imagem. Não entendi exatamente o que foi feito, talvez entendendo melhor eu consiga me virar. Não entendi a função abreJanela e nem aonde eu devo utiliza-la, nao entendi a variavel img da função maisGaleria e não entendi como e o que devo passar como parametro novoElemento. Poderia explicar por gentileza ?

Comment: Gostaria de saber exatamente pois com esse código ele retorna que "img is null"...

Comment: @GabrielOzzy por vezes estou no SOpt durante o trabalho e meio distraído. Havia um erro na minha resposta, o elemento que criei era `img` e devia ser `div` pois `#gallery` é uma `div` também, e aliás `img` não tem innerHTML. Agora corrigi.

Comment: mais uma vez obrigado pela ajuda. Porém, ainda não funciona... eu coloquei as duas funções no arquivo pgScript.js e removi o onload do body na página teste.html. O que será que pode ser ?

Comment: Mas eu lhe peço desculpa pela ignorancia, ocorre que também vivo numa correria enorme. Agora eu compreendi as funções e como elas funcionam, mas como eu passaria o parametro da função abreJanela de maneira dinamica ? Digo, sem digitar direto no código ?

Comment: consegui resolver o meu problema, postarei a resposta aqui em breve ! Obrigado pela atenção !